# Member function for nested list in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

Can someone show me the error in this code please?
I want to generalize the member function to support nested lists. I need to search thing inside the nested list and return the rest of the list when I found thing. I don't really understand whats wrong with the code below.

```
(define (memberk thing lis)              
  (cond
    ((null? lis) #f)
    ((list? (car lis))
     (cons (memberk thing (car lis))
           (memberk thing (cdr lis))))
    (else
     (if (equal? (car lis) thing)
         lis
         (memberk thing (cdr lis))))))
```

Expexted output: `(memberk 3 '(1 4 (3 1) 2))` = `'((3 1) 2)`
Actual output from the code above: `'((3 1) . #f)`

Comment: Can you spec out exactly what you want to get, in words and not just listing the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

So how I see this you would like the top level cons that has the key found somewhere in `car`. I'm thinking something like:

```
(define (memberk needle lst)
  (define (found? haystack)
    (or (equal? needle haystack)
        (and (pair? haystack)
             (or (found? (car haystack))
                 (found? (cdr haystack))))))
  (let loop ((lst lst))
    (cond ((null? lst) #f)
          ((found? (car lst)) lst)
          (else (loop (cdr lst))))))

(memberk '(a) '(a b (b (a) c) c d)) ; ==> ((b (a) c) c d)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I need to search the needle in lst. when I found the value that I search I return the list from this value

Comment: @mimi Wouldn't that make the example in your question `(memberk 3 '(1 4 (3 1) 2)) ; ==> (3 1)` instead of `((3 1) 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

It is a bit unclear what you want - since there is only one test case.

```
(define (memberk thing lis)
  (cond
    [(null? lis)
     #f]
    [(and (cons? (car lis)) (memberk thing (car lis)))
     => (λ (found) (cons found (cdr lis)))]
    [(equal? (car lis) thing)
     lis]
    [else
     (memberk thing (cdr lis))]))
```